# DefaultListModel in JList in JScrollPane, can't see the JList

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I'm trying to do a generic JList handled with a DefaultListModel inside a JScrollPane. However, I can't see the JList.

Here is the class :

FieldScrollList :

```
    public class FieldScrollList<T> extends JScrollPane {

        private DefaultListModel<T> listModel;


        public int length () {
            return listModel.size();
        }

        public FieldScrollList () {

            setBorder(new TitledBorder(this.getClass().getSimpleName()));
            setBackground(Color.PINK);

            listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
            JList<T> jList = new JList<>(listModel);
            add(jList);


            jList.setBorder(new TitledBorder(jList.getClass().getSimpleName()));


        }

        public void clear () {
            listModel.clear();
        }

        public void push(T t) {
            listModel.add(length(),t);
        }

        public <C extends Collection<T>> void pushAll(C coll) {
            coll.forEach(this::push);
        }

        public void pushAll(T[] coll) {
            for (T t : coll) {
                push(t);
            }
        }
    }
```

And Here is the class using it. In this example, I a FieldScrollList which sould display list items : hi and hello.

```
public class test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            //---------------------------------- Content initialization ------------------

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            FieldScrollList<String> list = new FieldScrollList<String>();

            //---------------------------------- Strings initialization ------------------


            ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
            strings.add("Hello");
            strings.add("Hi");
            strings.forEach(list::push);

            //---------------------------------- JPanel configuration --------------------

            panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
            panel.add(list);

            //---------------------------------- JFrame configuration --------------------

            frame.add(panel);
            frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550,600));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }).start();

    }
}
```

And the result is like that :

[image: GUI Created]

The goal of the borders and setbackgrounds are to display the location and area of the contents (visually)

I don't understand why the fields are not displayed

Comment: Do you really need to extend `JScrollPane` ?

Comment: I began using a JPanel, but I just need to be able to use it as a component. What should be the best ?

Comment: `revalidate();`
`repaint();`
try this after you add the jList

Comment: It didn't change anything, so i tried it on the jpanel after adding the jscrollpane, and it didn't change anything either

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume :  I would simply create an instance of the list, then add a `new JScrollPane(list);` . Indeed, the `add` method won't get you the expected result inside a `JScrollPane`, scroll panes work with _viewport views_ :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Comment: *"What should be the best ?"* A `JScrollPane`. But there is no need to **extend** the component just to use an instance of one. Pretty sure it was the extends part that @Berger was questioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't extend `JScrollPane`. You are not adding any functionality to the scrollpane. All those methods are related to the `ListModel` and have nothing to do with a `JScrollPane`.

```
add(jList);
```

Don't add components to a scrollpane. The `JScrollPane` is a compound component that contains `JScrollBars` and a `JViewport`. The `JList` needs to be added to the viewport.

Don't add the `JList` to the panel. You need to add the `JScrollPane` to the panel

Typically this is done with basic code like:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( list );
panel.add( scrollPane );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are created and manipulating Swing objects not on the EDT.  Your Runnable should be invoked by SwingUtilities.invokeLater inside static void main.

Comment: I wrote the thread stuff after seeing something like that, but I still can't understand why. Have you some documentation please ?

Comment: Your Thread code is wrong. The code is not executing on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. Note the tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Lists` which has a working example you could have used. Keep the link to the Swing tutorial handy for all Swing basics.

Comment: The cut a long story short Swing leverages having all graphic updates on one thread to coalesce changes in the graphics pipeline.  Your code with probably get away with it, but technically creating JComponents anywhere other than the EDT is wrong and considered bad practice.